# Clever regex and LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a directory. In this directory there are lots of various files. I need only thumbnails. So I wrote a regex to match those files.

Then, having all those matches files - I would like to make a dictionary that would have:

- the key as the extracted number from the filename (the matched number - see code below)
- the value as Image

  ```
      public readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<int, Image> thumbnails;

      ItemData(string directory)
      {
          this.directory = directory;

          var files = Directory.GetFiles(directory);

          Regex r = new Regex(directory + "\\thumbnail-([0-9]+).jpg", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);

          List<int> sizes = new List<int>();
          List<Image> images = new List<Image>();

          for (int i = 0; i < files.Count(); i++)
          {
              string result = r.Match(files[i]).Groups[1].Value;
              if (result != "")
              {
                  sizes.Add(Int32.Parse(result));
                  images.Add(Image.FromFile(files[i]));
              }
          }

          thumbnails = sizes.Zip(images, (s, i) => new {s, i}).ToDictionary(item => item.s, item => item.i);
      }
  ```

I truly believe this could be written in a very short and clear way. Could you please help me?

**Edited solution**

```
public readonly Dictionary<int, Image> thumbnails;

public ItemData(string directory)
{
    Regex r = new Regex("^thumbnail-([0-9]+)$", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);

    thumbnails =
        Directory.GetFiles(directory)
        .Select(f => new
        {
            file = f,
            match = r.Match(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f))
        })
        .Where(x => x.match.Success)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            size = Int32.Parse(x.match.Groups[1].Value),
            image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(directory, x.file))
        })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.size, x => x.image);
}
```

Comment: Your regex won't work; `directory` contains backslashes, which have a special meaning in regex. You should double the backslashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the best I could come up with:

```
public void ItemData(string directory)
{
    var r = new Regex(directory + "\\thumbnail-([0-9]+).jpg", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);

    thumbnails =
        Directory
            .GetFiles(this.directory)
            .Select(f => new
            {
                file = f,
                result = r.Match(f).Groups[1].Value
            })
            .Where(x => x.result != "")
            .Select(x => new
            { 
                size = Int32.Parse(x.result),
                image = Image.FromFile(x.file)
            })
            .ToDictionary(x => x.size, x => x.image);
}
```

I had to change the `IReadOnlyDictionary<int, Image>` to `IDictionary<int, Image>` to make the assignment work.

Comment: The Linq portion can be shortened significantly:  Directory.GetFiles(this.Directory).Select(r.Match).Where(m => m.Success).ToDictionary(m => int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value), m => Image.FromFile(m.Groups[0].Value));